# Facebook Canvas app file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk

I am havig issues with uploading a file to my Facebook canvas app (using Facebook SDK C#). Looks like Facebook doesn't send the file to my MVC controller when using [CanvasAuthorize]. The user does have the 'photo_upload' permission.

Do I have to set the 'setFileUploadSupport' setting? If so, how do I do this?

Thanks!
Edward

Answer (score 0):

You can use FacebookMediaStream. It will look similar to this.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
string attachementPath = @"C:\\image.jpg";

using (var file = new FacebookMediaStream
                {
                    ContentType = "image/jpge",
                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(attachementPath)
                }.SetValue(stream))
{
    dynamic result = fb.Post("me/photos", 
        new { message = "upload using Facebook C# SDK", file });
}
```